# show only true tables in AWS athena in one call

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I'm trying to figure out how to list all tables of a athena database in AWS within just one single call. Here's what i tried:

`SHOW TABLES`, this will list you all tables as well as all views in that particular database. I want to have only the actual tables, not the views.

Another approach i was thinking of is using nested statements such as
`with views as (SHOW VIEWS) SHOW TABLES NOT IN views`. However, it seems you cannot use those DDLs in nested statements.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `information_schema`:

```
select *
from information_schema.tables t
where not exists (
        select v.table_name
        from information_schema.views v
        where v.table_schema = t.table_schema
            and v.table_name = t.table_name
    )
```

Possibly you will need to add filtering on `table_schema` to exclude not relevant ones.

Comment: `select * from information_schema.views` is empty in my case. am i missing something?

Comment: @plazmakeks have no idea, TBH. Maybe something with permissions?